# Why does my program receives a "No job jar file set" error?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Belowing is my code, clearly, I have set the jar by class with `job.setJarByClass(`KnnDriver.class)`.

Could anyone help me debugging this?

```
import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class KnnDriver extends Configured implements Tool{
    /*
     *  args = N, test.csv, train.csv, outputpath
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new KnnDriver(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    }

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = getConf();
        conf.set("N", args[0]);

        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "K-Nearest-Neighbor mapreduce");        
        job.setJarByClass(KnnDriver.class);

        job.addCacheFile(new URI(args[1]));

        if (args.length != 4) {
            System.err.println("Number of parameter is not correct!");
            System.exit(2);
        }

        job.setMapperClass(KnnMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(KnnReducer.class);

        // TODO: specify output types
        job.setOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(DistClassPair.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        // TODO: specify input and output DIRECTORIES (not files)
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[2]));

        Path outputPath = new Path(args[3]);
        FileSystem.get(conf).delete(outputPath, true);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputPath);

        return(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : -1);
    }

}
```

In addition, here is the stack information

```
2016-02-25 04:00:31,240 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:<clinit>(62)) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2016-02-25 04:00:31,449 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation (Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(1173)) - session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
2016-02-25 04:00:31,450 INFO  [main] jvm.JvmMetrics (JvmMetrics.java:init(76)) - Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
2016-02-25 04:00:31,603 WARN  [main] mapreduce.JobResourceUploader (JobResourceUploader.java:uploadFiles(171)) - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
2016-02-25 04:00:31,650 INFO  [main] input.FileInputFormat (FileInputFormat.java:listStatus(283)) - Total input paths to process : 1
2016-02-25 04:00:31,697 INFO  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter (JobSubmitter.java:submitJobInternal(198)) - number of splits:1
2016-02-25 04:00:31,778 INFO  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter (JobSubmitter.java:printTokens(287)) - Submitting tokens for job: job_local225811898_0001
2016-02-25 04:00:32,014 INFO  [main] mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager (LocalDistributedCacheManager.java:symlink(201)) - Creating symlink: /tmp/hadoop-xupengtong/mapred/local/1456390831864/test.csv <- /Volumes/TONY/Big_Data/KnnMapReduce/test.csv
2016-02-25 04:00:32,019 INFO  [main] mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager (LocalDistributedCacheManager.java:setup(165)) - Localized file:/Volumes/TONY/Big_Data/KnnMapReduce/data/test.csv as file:/tmp/hadoop-xupengtong/mapred/local/1456390831864/test.csv
2016-02-25 04:00:32,058 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:submit(1294)) - The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
2016-02-25 04:00:32,059 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1339)) - Running job: job_local225811898_0001
2016-02-25 04:00:32,060 INFO  [Thread-21] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:createOutputCommitter(471)) - OutputCommitter set in config null
2016-02-25 04:00:32,064 INFO  [Thread-21] output.FileOutputCommitter (FileOutputCommitter.java:<init>(100)) - File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
2016-02-25 04:00:32,066 INFO  [Thread-21] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:createOutputCommitter(489)) - OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
2016-02-25 04:00:32,094 INFO  [Thread-21] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:runTasks(448)) - Waiting for map tasks
2016-02-25 04:00:32,095 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:run(224)) - Starting task: attempt_local225811898_0001_m_000000_0
2016-02-25 04:00:32,115 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] output.FileOutputCommitter (FileOutputCommitter.java:<init>(100)) - File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
2016-02-25 04:00:32,121 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree (ProcfsBasedProcessTree.java:isAvailable(192)) - ProcfsBasedProcessTree currently is supported only on Linux.
2016-02-25 04:00:32,121 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.Task (Task.java:initialize(612)) -  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : null
2016-02-25 04:00:32,124 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:runNewMapper(756)) - Processing split: file:/Volumes/TONY/Big_Data/KnnMapReduce/data/train.csv:0+4447014
2016-02-25 04:00:32,229 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:setEquator(1205)) - (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
2016-02-25 04:00:32,229 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:init(998)) - mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
2016-02-25 04:00:32,229 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:init(999)) - soft limit at 83886080
2016-02-25 04:00:32,229 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:init(1000)) - bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
2016-02-25 04:00:32,229 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:init(1001)) - kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
2016-02-25 04:00:32,233 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:createSortingCollector(403)) - Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
2016-02-25 04:00:32,352 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:flush(1460)) - Starting flush of map output
2016-02-25 04:00:32,360 INFO  [Thread-21] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:runTasks(456)) - map task executor complete.
2016-02-25 04:00:32,361 WARN  [Thread-21] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:run(560)) - job_local225811898_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(StringTokenizer.java:199)
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(StringTokenizer.java:221)
    at KnnMapper.setup(KnnMapper.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-02-25 04:00:33,061 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1360)) - Job job_local225811898_0001 running in uber mode : false
2016-02-25 04:00:33,062 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1367)) -  map 0% reduce 0%
2016-02-25 04:00:33,066 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1380)) - Job job_local225811898_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
2016-02-25 04:00:33,070 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1385)) - Counters: 0
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace error you are getting?

Comment: Where are you seeing the error you are reporting in the title of this? All I can see is a NullPointerException being thrown by your KnnMapper class.

Comment: I think your error is here `KnnMapper.setup(KnnMapper.java:67)`.

Comment: @mikea It is the first warning in the trace, but I too agree with you.

Comment: But still, though the program is essentially wrong with the exception you pointed out, why would there be a warn regarding "No job jar file set"?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that all the variables you use in map and reduce are initialized.
I had the same problem

Comment: @ArnonZilca Why do you think that this does not provide an answer? It clearly indicates what the OP needs to solve his issue.